# server side pagination using primeNg in Angular 6

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to implements server side pagination using primeNg in Angular and  database using  sequelize

Comment: Did you search at the `primeNG` official website.
Please check there ´https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/lazy´

Comment: yes i checked but not working

Comment: Can you show us what did you try till now please because so as you have asked it is not bringing up to much.

Comment: <p-table   [value]="listUser"  [style]="{'overflow':'auto!important'}" [paginator]="true"  [rows]="10" 
              (onLazyLoad)="loadCarsLazy($event)"></p-table> this is html

Comment: loadCarsLazy(event: LazyLoadEvent){
    debugger;
    console.log(event);
  } components but i am not getting proper responses and i am using angular 6